# error: method execute in class CoroutinesRoom cannot be applied to given types

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

**I am using coroutines with room database and while fetching data from room I am getting below error**

> \app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\co\location\locationapp\data\source\local\LocationDataDao_Impl.java:87:
>   error: method execute in class CoroutinesRoom cannot be applied to
>   given types;
>       return CoroutinesRoom.execute(__db, true, new Callable() {
>                            ^   required: RoomDatabase,Callable,Continuation   found:
>   RoomDatabase,boolean,>,Continuation
>   reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)   where R is a type-variable:
>       R extends Object declared in method execute(RoomDatabase,Callable,Continuation)   where
>   CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
>       CAP#1 extends Object super: Unit from capture of ? super Unit

**Below is my Dao class**

```
@Dao
interface LocationDataDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM location limit :limit offset :offset")
    suspend fun queryLocationData(limit: Int, offset: Int): List<Location>

    @Query("DELETE FROM location")
    suspend fun deleteAllLocationData(): Int

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertAllLocationData(locationData: List<Location>)

}
```

**Below is my repository class**

```
class LocationRepository @Inject
constructor(private val apiInterface: ApiInterface, private val locationDataDao: LocationDataDao) {

    suspend fun getLocationDataFromApi(limit: Int, offset: Int): List<Location> {
        try {
            return apiInterface.getLocationData(offset, limit).await()
        } catch (ex: HttpException) {
            throw ApiError(ex)
        }
    }

    suspend fun getLocationDataFromDb(limit: Int, offset: Int): List<Location> {
        return locationDataDao.queryLocationData(limit, offset)
    }


    suspend fun insertData(locationList: List<Location>) {
        locationDataDao.insertAllLocationData(locationList)
    }

    suspend fun deleteDataFromDB() {
        locationDataDao.deleteAllLocationData()
    }

}
```

**I am fetching data from a method like below**

```
 fun loadAfter() {
    Job job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { 
   val data = locationRepository.getLocationDataFromDb(BuildConfig.PAGE_SIZE, params.key)
            }    
    }
```

**Please let me know if further info is required**

Comment: not sure if you can insert a list. you should insert the object and insert it with a for-loop or something

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure that all room libraries have the same version in your app build.gradle:

```
...
dependencies {
  ...
  def room_version = "2.2.0-alpha02"
  implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
  implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
  kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```

See the [Declaring dependencies](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room) documentation section.

Comment: Solved for me. Thanks!

Comment: My problem wasn't a version difference, but rather `katp` on the `room-ktx` dependency rather than `implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to upgrade to the latest version.
I upgraded from `2.2.6 to 2.3.0` and the problem has been solved.

```
def room_version = "2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
```